# printer error message

Tags: 22.04, printing, hp

Ubuntu 22.04.3 (wayland), HPLIP 3.22.10, HP laserjet 1320 series printer.

When running Ubuntu 18.04, there were no problems using this printer.  Since upgrading to 22.04, I have this problem -

The first page prints fine, but then no other pages print execpt one page of very cryptic error messages:

***ERROR:

typecheck

OFFENDING COMMAND:

idiv

STACK

50000

--nonstringval--

--nonstringval--

-mark-

-mark-

-mark-

-mark-***

(Another printer connected to this same computer works just fine.)

Questions:

1. What do these messages mean?
2. Why did this printer work fine in 18.04, but not in 22.04?
3. How do I fix this so that this printer works correctly?

Comment: try uninstalling the printer then re-install under the new version of Ubuntu